# Is there a C# / Windows Forms equivalent to Android's runOnUiThread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Is there a C# / Windows Forms equivalent to Android's [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)?

For example, say I am running a (long-running) task on a worker thread and at the end I want to post the result to a GUI control (which of course I can't do from the worker thread). Is there a function as simple as [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) that would allow me to post that refresh-display for processing by the UI thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each control in WinForms inherits the `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` methods.

[Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) will run the delegate synchronously whereas [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) runs it asynchronously.

Comment: When is using the synchronous Invoke preferable to using the asynchronous BeginInvoke?

Comment: Hardly ever.  It's occasionally useful if the alternative is overrunning the UI input queue with a pile of async messages.

Answer (score 2):

A typical way to do this is with a System.Windows.Forms.Control:

```
control.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ... });
```

But, the control's handle must have already been initialized on the UI thread. A simple

```
IntPtr ignored = control.Handle;
```

on the UI thread will accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Control.Invoke` method.

From MSDN: "Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle."

Answer (score 1):

If you've got access to a winforms control or form, simply call [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) or [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) on that control or form.